# $x^{2}\frac{dy}{dx}\cos(\frac{1}{x}) - y\sin(\frac{1}{x}) =-1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I tried solving the equation by putting

$\frac{1}{x} = {t}$

so $$\frac{dt}{dx} = - \frac{1}{x^{2}}$$

and I put that into my equation which became

$$\frac{dy}{dt}\cos{t} + y\sin{t} =1$$

I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: $dt/dx = -1/x^{2}$. Then note

$$(y \cos(t))' = y' \cos(t) - y \sin(t)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get,
$$
\frac{dy}{dt}\cos{t} + y\sin{t} =1
$$
Dividing whole wquation by $cost$ ,
$$
\frac{dy}{dt} + y\tan{t} =\sec{t}
$$

Hence **Using Method of Integrating factor**,
$$
I.F.=e^{\int\tan{t}dt}=e^{\log{(\sec{t})}}=\sec{t}
$$
$$
(\sec{t})y=\int{(\sec{t}*\sec{t})dt}
$$
$$
(\sec{t})y=\tan{t}+C
$$
$$
y=\sin{t}+C*\cos{t}
$$
As $t=\frac{1}{x}$ so,
$$
y=\sin{(\frac{1}{x})}+C*\cos{(\frac{1}{x})}
$$
LINK : http://www.mathcentre.ac.uk/resources/uploaded/mathcentre-ode.pdf